# Can you make a decent video or gif of Thaddeus' bump?

Tags: discussion, moderators, bounty

Last night during *Rick and Morty*, *Adult Swim* aired a bumper card which mentioned our own beloved moderator, Thaddeus.  I'm trying to find a decent quality video or gif of the bump.  It read, in part:

[image]

[image]

My own attempts to get a video of it left much to be desired.

I would be willing to pay a bounty of 300 points for a good quality video or gif of the bump.  Post it here or in chat.

The episode was titled *Interdimensional Cable II:  Tempting Fate*.  It is available on putlocker, and should be on the Adult Swim website within a day or two.

Comment: I can pull it off my DVR.  I'll post something nice and high quality later this week.

Comment: @Keen - Much obliged.  I'm sure your colleague will be very grateful.

Comment: Lol, good one. Is that ~$600M **per annum**?

Comment: @thaddeus: did you see this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Tada: